# Iterating through directories throws non-iterator error

Tags: python, iterator, directory, subdirectory

I tried exact code on [this page](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/blob/master/recipes/Python/184602_Directory_Iterator/recipe-184602.py) to iterate through subdirectories. However, I am getting following error:

```
  File "dir_iterator.py", line 29, in <module>
    for x in it:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'iterdir'
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Note: I am using Python version 3.5.3 on Debian Stable Linux

Edit: As suggested by @DroidX86 in comments below, I am posting the code verbatim as copied from [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ActiveState/code/master/recipes/Python/184602_Directory_Iterator/recipe-184602.py):

```
import os

class iterdir(object):
    def __init__(self, path, deep=False):
    self._root = path
    self._files = None
    self.deep = deep
    def __iter__(self):
    return self
    def next(self):
    if self._files:
        join = os.path.join
        d = self._files.pop()
        r = join(self._root, d)
        if self.deep and os.path.isdir(r):
        self._files += [join(d,n) for n in os.listdir(r)]
    elif self._files is None:
        self._files = os.listdir(self._root)
    if self._files:
        return self._files[-1]
    else:
        raise StopIteration


# sample:
#   a deep traversal of directories which starts with a vowel
#
it = iterdir('.')
for x in it:
    p = os.path.basename(x)
    it.deep = p[0].lower() in "aeiou"
    print x
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Even it's copied verbatim from another source - links rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is written for python2. For any reason, if you want it to run with python3, change `def next:` to `def __next__:` and `print x` to `print(x)`. These two changes required to convert the python2 code in the link to python3.

```
import os


class iterdir(object):
    def __init__(self, path, deep=False):
        self._root = path
        self._files = None
        self.deep = deep

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._files:
            join = os.path.join
            d = self._files.pop()
            r = join(self._root, d)
            if self.deep and os.path.isdir(r):
                self._files += [join(d, n) for n in os.listdir(r)]
        elif self._files is None:
            self._files = os.listdir(self._root)

        if self._files:
            return self._files[-1]
        else:
            raise StopIteration


# sample:
#   a deep traversal of directories which starts with a vowel
#
it = iterdir('.')
for x in it:
    p = os.path.basename(x)
    it.deep = p[0].lower() in "aeiou"
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked code is written for python2.

you are running using python3.

either you will have to make changes to the code to make it work in python3 or you can use python2.